# Source for using more than 3 Hadassim?

Tags: minhag, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I’m looking for the source(s) for the custom to use more than 3 Hadassim with the Lulav. My personal custom is to use 9, and I’ve heard of a custom to use as many as 70! I remember seeing it brought somewhere, but haven’t been able to find it again. (I believe there are also those who say to add Aravos and not Hadassim)

Comment: See Rambam Lulav 7:7, OC 651:16. This used to be a lot more common.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10713/13811

Answer (score 1):

This site [writes](https://asktherav.com/11200-how-many-haddasim-should-be-used/)

> It is the Chabad custom to add multiple Haddasim to the standard
> three, adding at least another three. The greater the number of
> additional Haddasim, the better.
>
> In Sefer HaMinhagim page 65 it says: 4, 12, 13 or 26 but not 9, 68 or
> 69.
>
> The Rebbe’s personal custom is to take 36 since 5741. (In 5711 – 13;
> from 5712 till 5740 – 26).

Nonetheless, as DoubleAA noted above, the Shulchan Aruch OC (651:15) [poskins](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.651.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> לא יטול יותר מלולב אחד ואתרוג אחד אבל בערבה והדס מוסיף בה כל מה שירצה
>
> - One should not take more than one lulav and one etrog. However, one can add as many myrtle or willow as they want.