# Why do we say berachot on hanukah if it’s post-Torah

Tags: blessing, chanuka, derabanan

Since Hanukkah is not mentioned in the Torah, why do we say bercahot with hashem’s name, especially lehadlik ner which includes “asher kiddishanu bemitzvotav”. If hanukah is not part of the commandments directly and is derabanan, it seems a bit weird. I think I’m probably just mixing up some concepts I learned in my Yeshiva high school.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jeremy and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: For those interested, the question this question is marked as a duplicate of, is itself marked as a duplicate of: "[Who Commanded Us, and For What?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/32186/1368)"