# Source for a Maharal I learned a while back...help

Tags: sources-mekorot, creation, natural-phenomenon, maharal

A while back I learned a Marahal in which he says that God provided the general instructions to the natural process but did not provide details, rather nature took its course. One example he gave (I may not be remembering this part exactly) is that in creation of Man, God would have provided instructions for eyes, and nature, "seeing" that eyes would need protection, caused man to have eye lids.

My question is, WHERE IS THIS LOCATED!? I learned it inside around 8 years ago and I can say pretty confidently that its either Be'er Hagolah or Chidushei Agadot. I've searched somewhat and cannot locate it. Does anyone know this piece and can you provide the M"M (citation) please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found it! באר הגולא, באר הראשון, תלונה השלישי:

Context and summary: Maharal is defending what the people of his time and earlier times claimed: that the Rabbis of the Talmud engaged in Bal Tosif by adding Rabbinic law.  Maharal offers a defense that the Rabbis looked into the inner workings of God's relationship with nature.  They saw that God left it to nature to create the protections for the organs.  The Rabbis saw a parallel between themselves and nature: just as nature needed to create protections for the organs and limbs, so to the Rabbis had to create protections for the Torah.  I'm not sure I buy it as a true heter for Bal Tosif, but its definitely interesting and is the source that I was looking for.

השלישי הם המצות שגזרו חכמים גדר וסייג לתורה, וגם באלו מצות אין ספק שהם מתחברים אל התורה עצמה. כי תמצא מצות עשה שבתורה הם רמ"ח כמנין אבריו של אדם כמו שאמרו חכמים (מכות כ"ג, ב') ומאחר שהמצות הם במספר האברים א"כ יש למצות יחוס אל האברים. והרי החכימה הטבע לתת לאברים שמירה שלא יתקלקל האבר, כמו שתראה העינים שיש להם מכסה שלא יבא לעין קלקול, וכן יש הרבה אברים אשר יש להם שמירה שלא יתקלקלו, וא"כ איך לא יהיה שמירה למצות אלקית. כי לפי גודל ההיזק גזרה החכמה לעשות שמירה יותר, כמו שהחכימה הטבע לעשות אל העין שמירה הוא המכסה שהוא על העין, כי העין אבר חשוב מאד צריך אליו שמירה. וכן עשתה הטבע הצפרנים לאצבעות היד והרגלים, שלא יהיו נקופים בתנועת האדם, ושערות הראש שמירה לראש, וכן כל אבר ואבר לפי חשיבתו יש לו שמירה מבחוץ. ודבר זה הוא זולת האבר הדבר שהוא שמירה אליו. ובודאי האברים וצורתן הוא פעולת הש"י, ויש לייחס פועל זה יותר אל הש"י מלייחס זה אל פועל הטבע, רק כי המכסה שהוא לעין שהוא שמירת העין יש לייחס זה יותר אל הטבע. כך גוף המצוה סדר הש"י, רק שמירת המצוה שהוא מצוה דרבנן דבר זה גזרו ופעלו חכמים והם בני אדם ויש לייחס אותם אל הטבע, כי הש"י סדר אותם לפועל זה. וכמו ששמירת העין ושאר אברים נכנסין בגדר הבריאה, כך ג"כ הגזירות שגזרו חכמים לשמירת המצות נכנסים בגדר התורה. לכך חייב לברך עליהם אשר קדשנו וכו', כמו על מצות התורה. וכן לכל דבר שבעולם יש שמירה ותיקון ג"כ, שהש"י סדר אותו בחכמתו שיהיה נשמר מן ההיזק, ודבר זה ידוע למי שיודע בענין זה. ואיך לא תהיה שמירה למצות שבתורה, שיותר צריך שמירה אל המצות במה שיצר לב האדם רע מנעוריו ויש לחוש שיתקלקלו, ולפיכך צריך לגדרים וסייגים ולשמירה, כמו אברי האדם וכל אשר הוא תחת השמש יש לו שמירה, אשר על ידי אותה שמירה נשמר שלא יבא לידי קלקול, כך צריך שמירה וגדר למצות התורה. וכמו שהשמירה של האבר אין ראוי להיות שומר אל השומר, מפני שאי אפשר שיהיה דבר טפל אצל דבר שהוא טפל בעצמו, רק הדבר הוא טפל אצל העיקר. ולכך אמרו גם כן בכל מקום (ביצה ג', א') שאין גוזרין גזירה לגזירה, כי הגזירה האחת שהיא שמירה אצל המצוה מתחברת עם המצוה עצמה וטפילה היא אצל העיקר, אבל גזירה לגזירה אין לגזור כי אין הדבר טפל רק אל דבר שהוא עיקר, ודבר זה ענין מופלג מאוד. הרי התבאר ענין אלו מצות שהם מתחברים לתורה בחבור גמור במה שהם שמירת התורה, כמו שמתחבר השומר עם האבר עד שיכנוס בגדרו עד ששם האבר נקרא עליו. וכך אלו מצות שהם גדר לתורה אין ספק שיכנסו בגדר אחד עם התורה, עד כי שם תורה נאמר עליהם כאחד ודבר זה מבואר מאוד

Comment: +1 That's bal tosif; בל; not baal; בעל. Regarding Rambam's approach to why rabbinic additions arent bal tosif, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53364/8775. Regarding the broader question of why they are authorised to legislate, and why it isnt circular, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65924/what-is-the-basis-that-allows-rabbis-to-create-laws/77689?s=1|0.1006#77689.

Comment: Thanks.  I corrected the typos.  My transliteration has always been somewhat haphazard.  Yes, I am familiar with the various positions on bal tosif.  Yehudah Halevi has by far the most sobering of rationales: he says in Kuzari that the rabbis did in fact add but bal tosif didn't apply to them!  It's a very refreshing and scary answer all at once.  Refreshing because its nice to see a great mind Jewish mind take Occam's Razor and admit what seems obvious.  At the same time, scary because Y Halevi introduced a very slippery slope.