# If dairy and meat come from the same Star Trek replicator, would it be Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, technology, meat-and-milk, kashering-kosherization, popular-culture

Apologies for my limited understanding of Judaism, but as far as I am aware, Jewish dietary laws prohibit mixtures of meat and milk. I remember a friend's housemate requiring a second sink and set of kitchen utensils for this reason.

In the fictional setting of Star Trek, so called 'replicators' can make almost any foodstuff from directly from 'energy'.

Assuming (going by [Would synthesized meat be Kosher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14436/would-synthesized-meat-be-kosher)) replicator meat and dairy were certified as kosher separately, would there need to be a restriction on which ones made meat and which made dairy so there was no mixing?

Comment: We would need more details about how these things work in order to answer. (I don't know if such details even exist.)

Comment: @DoubleAA what sort of details would be needed? Let me know and I'll look into it and edit it in