Is Remilk dairy or pareve in Halacha
According to Halacha, is the animal free Remilk from Israel considered dairy for the purpose of seperating meat and dairy? Or no, since the milk is not from a live animal is it considered pareve and therefor isn’t prohibited from consumption with meat (as long as there is adequate showing it is not animal milk so there is no problem of Marit Ayin)? The reason I ask is because the article states

Founded in 2019, Remilk produces milk proteins via a yeast-based fermentation process that renders them “chemically identical” to those present in cow-produced milk and dairy products. The startup claims that the result is 100 percent similar to “real” milk.


https://www.israelhayom.co.il/judaism/judaism-news/article/13983289

related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14436/would-synthesized-meat-be-kosher

Another animal-free 'milk' comes from Perfect Day. On their website they say,

Perfect Day’s non-animal whey protein is Kosher Certified. Like all
food ingredients, our protein could end up in co-branded products that
contain other components which are not Kosher, or Kosher but not
Pareve. Please refer to product packaging to determine whether an
individual product is Kosher or Kosher Pareve.

I cannot find which authority gives the hechsher but it seems that the pure product is considered pareve.

Interesting data point, but hardly an answer to the question. It doesn't directly state it's pareve, and there's no reference to a rabbinic authority, and no rationale is offered. Plus it's not the same brand or even the same product.
