# What is the kashrut status of synthetic/in vitro meat?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, meat-and-milk, science

It was reported in the news today (at least in the UK) that another step forward has been made towards the creation of "synthetic meat". From [BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-23576143):

> The world's first lab-grown burger was cooked and eaten at a news conference in London on Monday.
>
> Scientists took cells from a cow and, at an institute in the Netherlands, turned them into strips of muscle which they combined to make a patty.
>
> Researchers say the technology could be a sustainable way of meeting what they say is a growing demand for meat.
>
> Critics say that eating less meat would be an easier way to tackle predicted food shortages.

What would be the kashrut status of this meat? Firstly I assume there would be the issue of shechita, but if we bypass that, then would this product be considered "meat" at all?

(I mean this in a somewhat tongue-in-cheek way, as I suspect the real answer is that no synthetic meat will ever be considered kosher by the Orthodox authorities, but I do find the question philosophically interesting.)

Comment: see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11269/759

Comment: Hi Allan, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope to see you around :)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I thought they changed it so that you couldn't mark as dupe of a question without answers. Anyway, [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11269/does-artificial-meat-grown-in-a-petri-dish-have-the-halachic-status-of-meat), which has answers, may be a better target.

Comment: Thanks both - I did try to find if this had already been asked, but I didn't find that one!