# Milk-free cheese: Is it kosher? Parve?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, technology, dairy

So according to [this article](http://www.msn.com/en-us/news/offbeat/milk-free-cheese-made-using-human-dna-strands/ar-AA2QyMS), scientists have created cheese by inserting DNA blueprints into a yeast. Essentially, the milk proteins are being created outside of any animal, through genetic engineering. The big question is, is it kosher? Would it be parve or dairy? If such a product was kosher, then supermarket cheese might be more approachable for many Jews.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11269/5323 (meat)

Comment: @Shokhet Very related! I was just thinking of the lab grown meat as I typed this question up.

Comment: [Spoiler](http://youtu.be/9IKVj4l5GU4).

Comment: Parve or dairy, I'd bet it's not that tasty.

Comment: ...I second that, Charles - milk, parve or plastic spongy mass...yum!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I emailed the OU with this question. Here's their response:

> Likely this cheese would indeed be pareve, but because of confusion
> (maris ayin) one would need to treat it like cheese. And one would not
> be permitted to eat it with meat.
>
> Since these products are not yet
> commercially available, and the OU has not been asked to certify these
> products, the OU poskim have not yet given psakim. If this ever comes
> to reality, the entire process will need to be studied very carefully.