# Kashruth of Perfect Day milk

Tags: dairy, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

News recently reported about a [company](http://www.perfectdayfoods.com/) in California that produces "Milk free Milk".

[image]

The process -- which is all in a lab -- involves yeast and genetically modify them by adding DNA from a cow to produce the exact same liquid as cow milk (without lactose for those suffering lactose intolerance and other benefits).

This being said, will this be dairy? If yes, for those who don't drink Chalav Stam, would this be non-Kosher?

Comment: Is there a Jew there watching?

Comment: I assume not. The question is of-course in context where normal milk would disqualify.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51119/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, I believe it's a dupe. but that post refers to a different company I believe, since it is 2 years old.

Comment: The answer would still apply in general no matter what company as the answer is that it would require investigation and hashgacha just like soy milk or any other mock cheese product.

Comment: @sabbahillel The difference from other mock milk here is that the DNA is from a cow and the end result have the same molecular structure as real milk.

Comment: That would be part of the discussion and analysis. It could even be a question similar to [Can meat grown from living cells be kosher? Is it eiver min hachai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69617/can-meat-grown-from-living-cells-be-kosher-is-it-eiver-min-hachai)

Comment: Maaris Ayin might be a problem and thus you would not be allowed to drink the milk with meat. However, if it was parve then you wouldn't have to wait six hours between eating meat.

Comment: @ezra the same applies to coffee rich and other pareve creamer