# In vitro meat -- further questions

Tags: kashrut-kosher, science, meat, slaughter-shochet-shecht, non-kosher-species

Related to this question: [Does artificial meat grown in a petri dish have the halachic status of meat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11269/does-artificial-meat-grown-in-a-petri-dish-have-the-halachic-status-of-meat?lq=1)

Assuming that in vitro meat becomes widespread and assuming that it would be hechshered per the above question, would the source material be able to be derived from *neveilot* (kosher animal, not slaughtered properly) or non-kosher animals, or would it need to be derived from properly shechted ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the source in [this answer to that question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30438/5323), Rabbi Menachem Genack of the OU had been [quoted](http://www.timesofisrael.com/has-the-era-of-the-kosher-cheeseburger-arrived/) as saying

> The tissue samples would have to come from an animal that had been slaughtered according to kosher rules

Comment: Whoops, missed that. It looks like an answer though.

Comment: Ahe article fails to explain the reasoning behind his statement that the animal must be slaughtered and not from a live biopsy. Can anyone provide more information to clarify that point?

Comment: I'd love that also, @IsaacKotlicky. I don't have any more info at the moment, though.