# Vaccines using aborted fetal cells

Tags: medicine, mussar-ethics, health-safety-shmira, abortion

A friend of mine informed me that a few coronavirus vaccines might have used aborted fetal cells during development and/or production. [What I have found](https://www.nebraskamed.com/COVID/you-asked-we-answered-do-the-covid-19-vaccines-contain-aborted-fetal-cells) by so far is that these cells were grown in laboratories from cells that are the remote descendants of cells once extracted from aborted fetuses in the '70s and '80s. Is it a concern for Jews? Were there any rabbis discussing this technology?

---

<sup>Possibly relevant: there was [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92542/15256) about cultured meat, and the answer there claimed that ritual slaughtering was required there.</sup>

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4980531/jewish/Can-I-Use-Vaccines-Made-From-Fetal-Tissue-or-Non-Kosher-Animals.htm https://jcamherst.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Vaccinations-and-Halachah-Three-Articles.pdf

Comment: @IsaacMoses why is cultured meat relevant? That's discussing the prohibition of ingesting non kosher. Vaccines aren't ingested.

Comment: @robev Kazi brought it up in a comment, so I moved it to the question post. It's possibly relevant because it's also about whether the origin of a cell line affects the status of cells grown from that cell line later on. Of course, that's not the only factor in play.